# Stepping through multiple threads

Tags: java

I have multiple threads that need to wait for each other to do a process. It has to be done this way because of requirements. If I show code and show expected output it will make sense. Here is my main class:

```
public static ThreadedJob job1, job2;
public static ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
public static void main(String[] rags) throws InterruptedException{
    job1 = new Job1("Thread1:");
    job2 = new Job2("Thread2:");
    job1.run();
    job2.run();
    threads.add(new Thread(job1));
    threads.add(new Thread(job2));
    if (job1.getCounter() > job2.getCounter()) {
        threads.get(0).wait();
        threads.get(1).notify();
    }
    if (job1.getCounter() < job2.getCounter()) {
        threads.get(1).wait();
        System.out.println(true);
        threads.get(0).notify();
    }
}
```

And here is the threaded job class, (Job1 and Job2 class for now just extend and call super(name) that is all)

```
public class ThreadedJob implements Runnable{



protected String name;
protected int counter = 0;
public ThreadedJob(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println(name + " job 1 complete");
    counter++;
    System.out.println(name + " job 2 complete");
    counter++;
    System.out.println(name + " job 3 complete");
    counter++;


}

public int getCounter(){ return counter; }

}
```

Here is the expected output:

`Thread1: job 1 complete
 Thread2: job 1 complete
 Thread1: job 2 complete
 Thread2: job 2 complete
 Thread1: job 3 complete
 Thread2: job 3 complete`

Here is the output from my code:

`Thread1: job 1 complete
Thread1: job 2 complete
Thread1: job 3 complete
Thread2: job 1 complete
Thread2: job 2 complete
Thread2: job 3 complete`

**Question:** How can I make it so the threads pause, allow to let go, then continue. Pretty much, how can I get them to step and wait to produce the expected output. Thanks!

**Important Note:** This needs to work for x amount of threads, I just am testing with 2. Also, the threads operate with different logic most of the time in the real application but aren't allowed to work at the same time.

Comment: I think you forgot to start your threads - you are running the runnables directly. The threads are not doing anything. Anyway, once you get that sorted, take a look at things like `CyclicBarrier` and `CountdownLatch`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I thought I did... How do I do that besides run()?

Comment: Ah. Well, you need to start from the very basic in threads. Using the `run` method runs the runnables **in the current thread** and doesn't start a thread. Take a look at the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Comment: Also, mutable stte access must be synchronized, and you should never, ever call wait() and notify() on threads. Actually, you should almost never use those methods, because there are much simpler higher-level abstractions in the concurrent package that you should use. Finally, the requirements should never tell how to do things. They should tell what to do.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I know you weren't very specific, but calling start() and nothing else made the program work exactly like it is supposed to... Maybe leave as an answer that you must start a thread?

Comment: Frankly, you **must** read up the concurrency tutorial on Oracle, and read all of it, including the synchronization parts and what issues can happen with concurrency. If your program worked just when you changed to "start", it did so by coincidence, probably due to the fact that `System.out.println` involves synchronization, and the tasks themselves are trivial. Using `start` is only the *first step* to correcting your real program, and @JBNizet has added some important things (you are using `wait()` and `notify()` on *threads* instead of *objects*, and doing it in the wrong place, for one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to read a bit about java multithreading, locking, and the java memory model.

They way you have written your code (each thread having its own counter, without any sync/locks when accessing it) ... basically means that many more things can happen than what you expect as potential output.

Meaning: both threads start running, and will increase their counters completely independent of each other.

Well, to be precise: it would be like that **if** you would be actually **using** those two other threads (which you aren't as you are calling **run** on your **Runnables**, not your threads).

So: when you would be actually going with three threads, then what your third thread sees when querying those counters is **completely** unpredictable. Your code is simply one huge race condition.

Comment: Have you noticed that no threads are actually running besides the main thread in that code?